# Setting up a test environment for SSIS 2008

Tags: sql-server, testing, ssis

I am looking to learn SQL Server Integration Services 2008 using SQL Server 2008  by getting hands on and messing around with it. I'd rather do this at home on a local install rather than a network, as it is just for testing and learning. I would like to install Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) as well.

What software do I need to install to achieve this? Also, what is the order (steps) to be taken to setup such an environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prerequisites for [SQL Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) are listed on the Microsoft website.

Do note that SQL Server 2008 is a *different* product from SQL Server 2008 R2. Calling it R2 was a stupid, stupid, confusing, and stupid marketing mistake IMAO. There are a number of implications between using one versus the other but it typically bites people in the backside when they try to restore a 2008R2 backup to a 2008 instance.

I would suggest buying the developer edition as it's only around $50 but if that is a hardship for you, the Enterprise Edition has a 180 day trial period.

Depending on your home hardware, it might even be a good idea to create a virtual machine to do this testing. The advantage to this is that if you do not get all of your testing done before the 180 period expires, you could roll that VM back to a checkpoint you took prior to installing the software.

While you are just starting your SSIS journey, I strongly recommend installing [BIDSHelper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/) after you've installed SSIS. It provides a host of "missing" features for SSIS, SSRS and SSAS development.

Also, look at the excellent [Stairway to Integration Services](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72494/) series on SSC (registration required). Andy Leonard has an excellent series that guides you through the pitfalls and best practices as they relate to SSIS.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, this is for 2008, not 2008 R2. Thanks for the info about the Developer versus Enterprise trial.

Also, thanks for the info about the add-in and series from SSC. Much appreciated!